# Error 504 when sending form data from website to email

Tags: php, hosting

I am trying to send a data from a form to my email.

I try using the form in my server (free hosting) and  it is fine. When I try to use it on another server (runs through cloudflare ) it gives me 504 gateway error. Any idea why?

Is it on my side or do I have to fix something?

My server page : http://mywg1.x10host.com/m1/

Cloudflare run page : http://wholesaledrywalltoronto.therenopros.ca/

the PHP for the form :

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['Email'])) {

// EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED

$email_to = "email.x@gmail.com";
$email_subject = "Drywall Pros Form";

function died($error) {
    // your error code can go here

    echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
    echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";

    echo $error."<br /><br />";
    echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";

    die();
}

// validation expected data exists

if(!isset($_POST['Name']) ||
      !isset($_POST['Email']) ||
      !isset($_POST['Phone']) ||
      !isset($_POST['comments'])) {
    died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
}

$Name = $_POST['Name']; // required
$Email = $_POST['Email']; // required
$Phone = $_POST['Phone']; // not required
$comments = $_POST['comments']; // required

$error_message = "";

$string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";

if(!preg_match($string_exp,$Name)) {
  $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}

if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
  $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
}

if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
  died($error_message);
}

$email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

function clean_string($string) {
  $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
  return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
}

$email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($Name)."\n";
$email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($Email)."\n";
$email_message .= "Phone: ".clean_string($Phone)."\n";
$email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";

// create email headers

$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
  'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
  'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
?>
<!-- include your own success html here -->

Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.

<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: code format, spelling errors

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it . For anyone who is having same errors . It is probably because the server you are working with only allows SMTP and not the PHP mail function.